# Tiny server/client setup - server doesn't respond. All code provided

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, vows

I'm teaching myself Coffeescript/node and, of course, the only way to do this is with TDD. That means I'm also teaching myself vows. There are, I think, at least two problems. One is -- where does the asynchronous code to get the HTTP response lie? And the other is -- why won't the server send me a response back? The console displays "Request sent" but it does not display "Request received."

Here is the test file:

```
vows = require 'vows'
assert = require 'assert'
EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter

Server = require('./web').WebServer
Client = require('../lib/client').Client
Request = require('../lib/request').Request

PORT = 8080
SERVER = new Server PORT
SERVER.start()
CLIENT = new Client PORT, 'localhost'
REQUEST = new Request 'GET', '/'

vows
  .describe('Sending a request to the server')
  .addBatch
    'The request is sent': 
      topic: -> 
        CLIENT.transmit(REQUEST, @callback)
        return

      'The response should be what the server sent back': (err, request) ->
        body = ""
        request.on 'response', (response) ->
          response.on 'data', (chunk) -> body += chunk
        assert.equal body, /Ooga/

  .export(module)
```

Here is the WebServer object:

```
Http = require('http')

exports.WebServer = class WebServer

  processRequest = (request, response) ->
    console.log 'Request received!'
    console.log request
    response.writeHead 200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'} #, 'Content-Length':'6'}
    response.write 'Ha-ha!'
    response.end

  constructor: (@port) ->
    @server = Http.createServer processRequest

  start: ->
    @server.listen @port

  stop: ->
    @server.close()
```

Next up is the client code - also very simple.

```
Http = require 'http'
Request = require('./request').Request

exports.Client = class Client

  constructor: (@port, @host) ->
    @httpClient = Http.createClient @port, @host
    @sentence = "I am a Client"

  transmit: (request, callback = null) ->
    req = @httpClient.request request.method, request.pathName
    req.end
    console.log "Request sent!"
    if callback
      callback(null, req)
    #req.on 'response', (res) ->
    #  callback(null, res)
      #request.on 'data', (chunk) -> callback(null, chunk)
    #callback(null, request)
```

And finally, the 'request' object.

```
exports.Request = class Request
  constructor: (@method, @pathName) ->

  method: ->
    @method

  pathName: ->
    @pathname

  responseBody: ->
    @body

  setResponseBody: (body) ->
    @body = body

  appendToResponseBody: (chunk) ->
    @body += chunk
```

All this is so simple that I really can't tell why the server doesn't seem to be working. I'm not even worried, yet, about where the asynchronous code should be to get the information back from the server, but I'd like to figure that out too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, you've made a classic mistake: You wrote

```
req.end
```

where you meant

```
req.end()
```

So, your request wasn't actually being sent at all, despite your console's claims to the contrary! (I see a `response.end` in your code as well.)

Incidentally, Vows test code is pretty, but it's also a complex framework with some subtle gotchas. You may want to try something simpler, like [nodeunit](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit).

Oh, and if you really hate parentheses, you can write `do req.end` instead of `req.end()`, but this isn't a common style.

Comment: Gah! Thank you. I am new to Javascript as well. I am learning very very fast about the vows gotchas, but I really want a test framework in which I can use Coffeescript. I didn't think nodeunit allowed that.. Does it?

Comment: It's not well documented, but nodeunit has actually supported CoffeeScript for a year now: https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit/pull/6 Just run `nodeunit test.coffee`.

Comment: Neat. Now if I could just figure out how to get the callbacks working... But that's another question. Coming right up!